# Does the English word "have" have a closer relationship with German "haben" or French "avoir"?

Tags: etymology, history

I see the English auxiliary verb *have* is very similar to Romance counterparts like Portuguese *haver*, Spanish *haber* or Italian *avere* and it appears to me that they have some historical relationship. It also adds to that guess that English has a predominant portion of Old French (*avoir*).

On the other hand, taking the Germanic origin of English and my belief that such a basic verb can't have a foreign origin, I also think that *have* has Germanic history, as seen by its old conjugation table closer to German (*thou hast / du hast* etc., but German uses *werden* more instead).

So my question is, which one is closer to English *have*? Germanic origin or Romance (Latin) origin?

Comment: ['From Middle English haven, from Old English habban, hafian (“to have”), from Proto-Germanic *habjaną (“to have”), durative of *habjaną (“to lift, take up”), from Proto-Indo-European *kh₂pyéti, present tense of *keh₂p- (“to take, seize, catch”). Since there is no common Indo-European root for a transitive possessive verb have (notice that Latin habeō is not related to English have), Proto-Indo-European probably lacked the have structure.'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have#Etymology_1)

Comment: Latin _habēre_ 'to have' (the source of the Romance auxiliaries like _avoir_) can't be cognate to English _have_ because of Grimm's Law. Modern English _have_ starts with an /h/. It comes from a Proto-Indo-European root that started with *k; one of the rules in Grimm's Law changed PIE *k to Proto-Germanic *h. That root also showed up in Latin, as _capere_ 'to seize'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Online Etymology Dictionary the Old English origin of "have" was "habban" and that it originated from Proto-Germanic:

> have (v.)
>  Old English habban "to own, possess; be subject to,
>   experience," from Proto-Germanic *habejanan (source also of Old Norse
>   hafa, Old Saxon hebbjan, Old Frisian habba, German haben, Gothic haban
>   "to have"), from PIE root *kap- "to grasp." Not related to Latin
>   habere, despite similarity in form and sense; the Latin cognate is
>   capere "seize.
>  [Source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/have#etymonline_v_6219)

Note the sentence that starts "Not related to Latin habere", and its continuation.

So English "have" came from Old English "habban", which in turn came from the Proto-Germanic *habejanan, which came from Proto-Indo-European root *kap- "to grab". The PIE root *kap- being the origin of Old English "habban" is also attested in Wikipedia's 
[Indo-European vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_vocabulary) article in the chart.

So English "have" doesn't at all come from a Romance language from what I've seen, as you rightly suspected. The Italian "avere" and Spanish "haber" do.
[Italian avere](https://etimo.it/?term=avere&find=Cerca)
[Spanish haber](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?haber)

Latin "habere" from the two sources I checked originated from a different PIE root *gʰabʰ- or *ghabh-, though how it came to be "habere", I have no idea.

The following explains the shifts of sounds from a PIE to Proto-Germanic some time in the first millennium BC, so you can see how it got from *kap to *habejanan. 
[Proto-Germanic Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language#Grimm's_and_Verner's_law)

So to answer your question, "have" is closer to German "haben" because there is no relation with "habere" or "avoir"; "habere" has a different PIE origin. Proto-Germanic *habejanan is the source of both German "haben" and English "have".

Comment: The Latin cognate of English _have_ is _capere_ 'seize, capture'. An English /h/ from PIE *k makes you look for a Latin root with a /k/, like _heart ~ cardium, hound ~ canis, head ~ caput_, etc.